# LED forward or reverse bias

Tags: semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

Are LEDs connected in forward bias or reverse bias? A recent question I got wrong said that LEDs are connected in reverse bias, but a general Google search tells me LEDs connected in forward bias light up.

Here's the question:

Light Emitting Diode is

A) A lightly doped p-n junction diode connected in Reverse Bias.

B) A lightly doped p-n junction diode connected in Forward Bias.

C) A heavily doped p-n junction diode connected in Forward Bias

D) A heavily doped p-n junction diode connected in Reverse Bias.

And it tells me the correct answer is D. Am I missing something?

Comment: LEDs are operated in forward bias.

Comment: The following might be related/helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94225/dependence-of-intensity-of-a-led-on-forward-bias-voltage

Answer (score 0):

An LED works like any standard diode.  The current must overcome a small reverse electric field due to chemical effects.  Some electrons in the N-doped side seep across to the P-doped side so as to create that reverse electric field.  Once circuit voltage overcomes this, current flows freely from the slightly higher voltage side to the slightly lower potential side.  This voltage is provided by the rest of the circuit.  This voltage drop results in a release of photons for all standard diodes.  LEDs emit photons of a frequency our eyes can see.